# How can make my code give an error message when name input is the same?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning from Bjarne Stroustrup's beginner book, and I am at chapter 4 exercise 19, so please don't use code above my level. I don't quite get it why the `if(name == names[i])` doesn't work.
So this is my code so far:

```
/*
Vladar Akos
Chapter 4 Exercise 19.
2018.03.26

Write a program where you first enter a set of name-and-value pairs, such as Joe 17 and Barbara 22. For each pair, add
the name to a vector called names and the number to a vector called scores (in corresponding positions, so that if
names[7]=="Joe" then scores[7]==17). Terminate input with NoName 0. Check that each name is unique and
terminate with an error message if a name is entered twice. Write out all the (name,score) pairs, one per line.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>scores;
    std::vector<std::string>names;
    std::string name = " ";
    int score = 0;
    bool first = true;
    std::cout << "Please write in a name and a score (terminate input with 'NoName') : \n";
    while ((std::cin >> name >> score) && (name != "NoName") && (score != 0))
    {
        if (first == true)
        {
            scores.push_back(score);
            names.push_back(name);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
            {
                if (name == names[i]) std::cout << "Same name as before!\n";
                else
                {
                    scores.push_back(score);
                    names.push_back(name);
                }
            }
            first = false;
        }
        std::cout << "Please write more names and scores: ";        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << names[i] << '\t' << scores[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

What can I do to make the program throw an error message when a name is entered twice? 
P.S.: this is my first post, so sorry if something is wrong

Edit: Thank you for your help! This was a dumb mistake on my part. **Swapnil**'s answer was the one that solved my issue but everyone helped a lot.

Comment: Check the names in the `names` vector against the new name

Comment: `first` will never become `false`. So the `else` part will never happen. If you knew [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) you would have found it out very quickly yourself.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did that but it dosn't change anything and the output remains the same. If I write **a 22** and **a 22** it will still print out both of them and won't give an error message.

Comment: It changes loads and the output cannot possibly remain the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But yes 'first' will become 'false' after the first input. Otherwise I wouldn't get any results at the end. I think debugging is the next chapter.

Comment: If `first == true`, then you do the action in that branch. Then you skip the `else` part (where you do `first = false`) and print the output. Then the loop iterates, and `first == true` is *still* true.

Comment: I did this but nothing changed : `if (names[i] == name) std::cout << "Same name as before!\n";`

Comment: See what some programmer dude said. this should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>scores;
    std::vector<std::string>names;
    std::string name = " ";
    int score = 0;
    bool first = true;
    std::cout << "Please write in a name and a score (terminate input with 'NoName') : \n";
    while ((std::cin >> name >> score) && (name != "NoName") && (score != 0))
    {
        if (first == true)
        {
            scores.push_back(score);
            names.push_back(name);
        }
        else
        {
            bool duplicate = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
            {
                if (name == names[i])
                    duplicate = true;
            }

            if(duplicate)
            {
                std::cout << "Same name as before!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                scores.push_back(score);
                names.push_back(name);
            }
        }
        first = false;
        std::cout << "Please write more names and scores: ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << names[i] << '\t' << scores[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

put the false outside the else and then added the bool flag which we be checked for duplication before inserting into vector

Along with output

```
Please write in a name and a score (terminate input with 'NoName') :
JON
20
Please write more names and scores: SAM
50
Please write more names and scores: PETER
50
Please write more names and scores: PETER
70
Same name as before!
Please write more names and scores: SAM
89
Same name as before!
Please write more names and scores: NoName
0
JON     20
SAM     50
PETER   50
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: Yep that's better :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make `first` `false` as soon as you process first input, otherwise it will never enter else. Put `first = false` outside of `else` statement. Another problem is that once you found out that there is duplicate you should stop searching, aka break for loop.:

```
while ((std::cin >> name >> score) && (name != "NoName") && (score != 0)) {
    if (first == true) {
        scores.push_back(score);
        names.push_back(name);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            if (name == names[i]) {
                std::cout << "Same name as before!\n";
            }
            else {
                scores.push_back(score);
                names.push_back(name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    first = false;
    std::cout << "Please write more names and scores: ";        
}
```

Comment: This is not the only problem. You're still pushing `score` and `name` too many times.

Comment: I just figured this out thank you very much. Dumb mistake. Leaving it inside the else statement. What a rookie mistake.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you mean by 'pushing score and name too many time?' Using them too many times?

Comment: @VladarAkos, he is (@LightnessRacesinOrbit) right. If you dont break the loop it will add the duplicate eventually.